I need a measure in PowerBI gives the equivalent weekday vs the same WEEKDAY of the previous year
I have a weekday vs previous year weekday requirement that does not seem to be common in the Retail industry.  I have found no articles or videos that happens to address this issue.  My employer wants to compare the first Monday of each month to the first Monday of the same month, previous year, the first Tuesday, Wednesday, etc., for the entire month.  I have a Dates table (marked as such) that relates to my Orders table.  I have already come up with a formula for getting the proper date of the previous year.  It is a calculated column in the Dates table called Offset_Date.  So May 1, 2024 (Wed) DATE equates to May 3, 2023 (Wed) Offset_Date.  So this part I have already figured out.  The problem is that I can't seem to get this year'ss Daily Sales Total and the equivalent Daily Sales Total LY for the equivalent date in the previous year.
As I said, I already have the correct date as Offset date.  In the sales transaction table I have a measure for
Daily_Total = SUM(Sales[TotalPrice])

I added a measure for
Daily_Total_LY = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Sales[TotalPrice]), 
    Dates[Offset_Date]
)

however it DOES NOT give me the sum from the previous year.  It give the same sum as this year.  I have also tried
Daily_Total_LY = 
CALCULATE(
    SUMX(Sales, SUM(Sales[TotalPrice])), 
    DateTable[Offset_Date]
)

However that returns a huge number, implying it isn't using Offset_date as a filter.
I suspect the first formula returns the same values because it is the Date column that relates to the Sales table, so Offset_date is irrelevant.  I haven't a clue on the 2nd formula.  Any direction would be appreciated.

Can you just shift backwards 52 weeks or 364 days? That would be the sort of equivalent Weekday of the year, right?

Can you please try this below measure-
Daily_Total_LY = 

var this_row_offset_date = min(Dates[Offset_Date])

RETURN
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Sales[TotalPrice]), 
    FILTER(
        ALL([Sales]),
        Dates[Date] = this_row_offset_date
    )    
)


Thank you for your response.  Unfortunately, this isn't working.  The error I get is "A single value for Dates[Date] cannot be determined.  This can happen When a measure contains many values . . ."  I should note:  The date column in my dates table, defines the table itself::  Dates = CALENDAR(date(2020,1,1), date(2030,12,31).  Should I be using a different column?

Can you please try the adjusted code?

The above change fixed the Dates[Offset_date] but I am still getting the same error for Dates[Date].

Then please add sample data and your expected output.

Maybe I need to share the broader situation.  I have a Sales transaction table, which relates to an Orders table through the OrderID.  The Orders table, in turn JOINS to my Dates calendar table, through the Date column in each.  The Sales table does not redundantly store the OrderDate, so I cannot directly join the Sales table to the Dates table.  I have to go through the relationship with Orders.  In the Sales table, I have a measure for DailyTotal = SUM([TotalPrice]).  When I create a visual with DailyTotal that is broken out by date, it automatically totals by date.

This is why this measure is not specifically telling the measure to aggregate by date, although I think it should.  What I am trying to do is have another column in my visual that displays the daily total, but from the same Day of the Week in the previous year.  To this end, I have a calculated column in my Dates table that correctly calculates the appropriate date from the previous year.  So and excerpt of my Dates table is
Date               OffsetDate
Wed 5/1/24    Wed 5/3/23
Thur 5/2/24    Thur 5/4/23
Fri    5/3/24    Fri    5/5/23
The OffsetDate is not JOINED to another table

My problem is I cannot create a measure in my Sales table that returns the right total for the previous year's Offset date.  It either returns the same value as this year's date, or a sum that makes no sense (way to large).  I hope this provides some clarity.

Big explanation often make the understanding hard. You can provide a simple sample dataset for your case and then the visual you wants to achieve. You can also share the .pbix file with sample data to people so that they can download and test your case.

Okay, I will work to get my pbix file posted here, in a much reduced size.  Perhaps just 5 days of data for May/24 and 5 days for May/23.  I would think that is enough to demonstrate the problem.  I have not done this before, so it may take me awhile to figure out how.
